# JavaScript/TypeScript - Callback not removed, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Colleagues, I can prove with logs that removing listener in some public component does not work. First, I see the listener is still called, second, I never see second console output, which puzzles me even more.

```
const scanListeners = []
...
function removeListener(callback) {
    console.log("About to remove listener")
    scanListeners = scanListeners.filter(listenerCallback => listenerCallback !== callback)
    console.log("Listener removed")
}
```

Could this be explained with some JavaScript specifics? I am not a huge expert in JS but still some years of work and I still cannot explain what happens.

BTW the component is invoked in ReactNative environment, like this:

```
const listener: Component.callBack = (code) => {
    processCode(code)
    dispatch(fetchList(code));
    try {
      Component.removeListener(listener);
    }
    catch { }
  };
```

P.S. Listener adding code:

```
function addScanListener(callback) {
  const listenerAlreadyExists = scanListeners.some(listenerCallback => listenerCallback === callback)
  if (!listenerAlreadyExists) {
      scanListeners.push(callback)
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are using named functions you should be removing the listeners via [.removeEventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) instead of setting the array reference like that

Comment: ````console.log("Listener removed)```` Try closing the quotes?

Comment: `function removeListener` does not exactly look like the method that you're calling as `Component.removeListener(listener);`. Please provide a complete [mcve], also including the code that puts the `listener` inside the `scanListeners` in the first place

Comment: Added code which adds listener. My callback is an anonymous function.

Comment: what are you adding the listeners to? because here you only removing the references to the listeners you added to the array. If these are not standard event listeners can you explain what these are?

Comment: @AndyVictors Please post a complete code snippet that we can run to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const scanListeners = []
...
function removeListener(callback) {
    console.log("About to remove listener")
    scanListeners = scanListeners.filter(listenerCallback => listenerCallback !== callback)
    console.log("Listener removed")
}
```

In this this case you are trying to reassign **const** variable.

Comment: Oh yeah.that was the reason! Thank you, your observation was a key.